# Can I login to an application with function app to monitor its status under private network?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an HTTP web application hosted in Azure VM which is not publically accessible. The application requires a username and password to load in the browser. Now I want the azure function to check if the application is up and running or not using the user name and password so that it can pass through the authentication.
So is there anyone who can suggest to me if there is any way to do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the username and password part. :) You can integrate an Azure Function into a VNET so that it can connect to internal resources, such as your VM (and the app) - but I'm not sure if that would be sufficient in your example. Could you elaborate a bit more on your requirements please?

Comment: Alright, I want my function to get HTTP status from my web app which is hosted in a VM., and that application is authenticated through windows authentication (IIS). So it requires a user name and password.